# ssh command does not exit even after doing its job

Tags: unix, ssh

```
ssh GJMEHUL@10.1.0.61 'more /home/GJMEHUL/.bash_history > /home/GJMEHUL/smsc_cmdlog_12Apr12_GJMEHUL.txt'
```

The above command which i've stored in a script called alarmtest.sh. Ive already set ssh keys. the problem is even though the command is doing its job it does not stop and I have to manually kill it using Ctrl+C.

When I tried the command below in a script:

```
ssh GJMEHUL@10.1.0.61 'who > /home/GJMEHUL/smsc_cmdlog_12Apr12_GJMEHUL.txt'
```

it worked perfectly.

Why is ssh command behaving like this?

Comment: `more` command needs interactivity. Please use `cat`.

Comment: @DeepakAtish - You might have noticed that I edited out the note about downvoting, in your question. You won't be downvoted for asking good/reasonable questions (and this question is quite fine IMO) and when its clear you've tried reasonably enough, to help yourself, before asking. Its best to avoid writing such notes. Finally: Welcome to SO, and good luck!

Comment: hahaha .. it happens again n again on stack over flow.. some retard downvoted me again . HAHA @ArjunShankar

Answer (score 3):

The more command is interactive.

You should use cat or head or tail.

Comment: Didn't know that about more .cat works,i know but i was told to use only more command. now that it cant be done, i guess cat is the only way

Answer (score 1):

You use "more", which waits for user interaction. Maybe you'd rather like to use cat or a simple cp?